# Cannot delete products from admin

Tags: magento-1.9, product, admin, database, error

When i delete products from admin it give error message

```
SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1690 BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(`ponicosmetics`.`tag_summary`.`products` - 1)'
```

query was:

```
UPDATE `tag_summary` SET `products` = products - 1 WHERE (tag_id IN ('7', '8', '30', '60', '61', '65', '86', '87', '88', '210'))
```

this.

I already follow following steps:

- Go into your database using PhpMyAdmin.
- Do a backup (always a good practice to back-up first).
- Select the Magento database you’re using.
- Select table sales_flat_quote (on second page).
- Select structure tab
- Select ‘change‘ on row called ‘items_count‘
- Go to the drop-down on the column named ‘Attributes‘ and change value to the very top value which is blank ‘(no value)‘, as opposed to the default selection ‘UNSIGNED‘ .
- Click save, and you’re good to go!

But this error "SQLSTATE[22003]:

```
Numeric value out of range: 1690 BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(`ponicosmetics`.`tag_summary`.`products` - 1)', query was: UPDATE `tag_summary` SET `products` = products - 1 WHERE (tag_id IN ('7', '8', '30', '60', '61', '65', '86', '87', '88', '210')) "
```

has comes .
Please suggest me any solution.

Comment: You got the solution ?

Comment: Not yet.. Please let me know..

Answer (score 2):

The message says, that the column is still `UNSIGNED`. The steps that you followed have changed the `items_count` column, but actually the problem is in the `products` column.

But this would only be a workaround to allow negative numbers in the column. A negative product count does not make sense, so the root problem is that your data in `tag_summary` index is inconsistent.

You should reindex the **Tag Aggregation Data** index and try again.